# Reading LM35 temperature sensor with atmega328p

Tags: microcontroller, avr, microprocessor, atmega328p, lm35

I want to read the temperature using LM35 and atmega328p so when the temperature equals or less than 30 a red LED (PINB0) will be turned ON, otherwise a green LED (PINB1) will be ON but I did not get that. Red LED is always ON and the green one is always OFF.
LM35 sensor is connected to PINC0.

I tried the following code and it has no errors, but it doesn't work. Also I'm not sure about temperature conversion[temp=(adc_result0)*(500.0/1023.0);].

```
#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 1600000UL
#endif
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void adc_init()
{
  // AREF = AVcc
  ADMUX = (1<<REFS0);
  // ADC Enable and prescaler of 128
  ADCSRA = (1<<ADEN)|(1<<ADPS2)|(1<<ADPS1)|(1<<ADPS0);
}

// read adc value
uint16_t adc_read(uint8_t ch)
{
  // select the corresponding channel 0~7
  ch &= 0b00000111;  // AND operation with 7
  ADMUX = ADMUX|ch;

  // start single conversion
  // write '1' to ADSC
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADSC);

  // wait for conversion to complete
  // ADSC becomes '0' again
  while (ADCSRA & (1<<ADIF) == 0);
  ADCSRA |= (1<<ADIF);
  return (ADC);
}

int main()
{
  DDRB=0xFF;
  DDRC=0x00;
  uint16_t adc_result0; 

  // initialize adc and lcd
  adc_init();

  while (1)
  { 
    float temp;
    adc_result0 = adc_read(0); // read adc value at PD0
    temp=(adc_result0)*(500.0/1023.0); // finding the temperature
    //temp = temp/10-273.15; //in c
    _delay_ms(100);
        
    if (temp <= 30) 
    {
      PORTB=0b00000001;
    }
    else
    {
      PORTB=0x00000010;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not what you asked about, but series resistors to the LEDs are missing. Where are your decoupling capacitors?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Wrong result? No result?  Explodes in a flash of green with purple smoke?

Comment: Please post code as text with the code tags instead of posting pictures of the code.

Comment: doesn't work means only the red LED is ON. I did not get the output that I want

Comment: Please edit that into your question as this is vital information.

Comment: Your code says PD0 for the input, actual input for channel 0 is PC0 but the connection is to PC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the formula, but that formula is for an ADC ref voltage of 5 VDC.

The ADC value (conversion result) is:

$$
X_{ADC}=\frac{V_{ADC}}{V_{ADCREF}}*1023
$$

If your ADC ref voltage is 5 VDC then a measurement result of 1023 means 5 V voltage read on ADC pin. LM35 generates 10 mV per degree Celsius. Putting all the info to the above formula you'll get the following formula for the read temperature:

$$
X_{ADC}=\frac{V_{ADC}}{V_{ADCREF}}*1023=\frac{T\ \mathrm{10mV}}{\mathrm{5000mV}}*1023 \Rightarrow T=500 \frac{X_{ADC}}{1023}
$$

You should apply voltages to AVCC and AREF pins to make sure that the simulator does not read 0V reference. Plus, I'm not sure but you may want to explicitly define in the code that where the VREF will be get from.

Comment: I connected them to a voltage supply but then the red LED is always ON and the green one does not work at all, even when the temperature is too low. u can see the result above, i added it just now

Comment: @MuntadherMohammed So you programmed your MCU so that it sets PB0 high when the read temperature is less than or equal to 30°C. And it's working as expected. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: but PB0 is always high even if the temperature is above 30 and the green led never turns on.

Comment: @MuntadherMohammed You are trying to read ch0 but your sensor is connected to ch2.

Answer (score 2):

In C, dividing an int by another int gives an int result. So, 499/500 is zero. So you should mind your type conversions and use something like:

```
temp = adc_result * (500.0/1023.0)
```

Using ".0" at the end of your numbers makes sure they're floats. If adc_result is an int, multiplying by a float makes sure the result is a float.

Note about debugging:

"The LED doesn't work" isn't helpful. Even if you explain "I expected that the green led will turn on and the red led off when the temperature sensor is below 30C, and the red led is turned on and the green led is off when the temperature equals or more than 30 C".

What you need to do is print the ADC result register on the serial port, because that will give you much more information than a LED.

For example, if the ADC is not working, you'll probably always read zero. If the voltage reference is wrong, then you'll get an incorrect value. So, just printing the value on the serial port allows to discriminate between several potential different bugs.

Comment: I rechecked again about this matter but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Again, what does "doesn't work" mean? It's very hard to help solve a problem when you don't know what it is.

Comment: LEDs are not working. I inserted the output of the circuit above.

Comment: Again, "LEDs are not working" does not explain what's happening. Please state in your question exactly what is happening and what you expected to happen.

Comment: I expected that the green led will turn on and the red led off when the temperature sensor is below 30C, and the red led is turned on and the green led is off when the temperature equals or more than 30 C

Comment: Please EDIT that into your original question, along with what actually happened.

Comment: You can print the value of your variable using the serial port to debug it.